# cassandra Custom defined data type: unable to find the abstract class

Tags: cassandra, custom-data-type

I am trying to implement Cassandra Custom Data type with JAVA , source code i used is at http://java.dzone.com/articles/custom-cassandra-data-types

with only difference , that package is cqltypes.

created the jar file file and placed it in installation lib directory, as mentioned by article.

But , when i call it in cqlsh: 
CREATE TABEL test2.state2(state 'cqltypes.UnitedStatesState');

I get an error << ErrorMessage code=2000 [Syntax error in CQL query] message = "Error setting type cqltypes.UnitedStatesState: Unable to find abstract-type class 'cqltypes.UnitedStatesState' " >>

Answer (score 0):

Hope someone could be benefited from this:

I was trying to install on windows, there in order to get any jar file change reflected u need to restart service.

One problem in windows cassandra is you cannot stop it, u have to restart the machine.
Even if u do, custom jars are not getting picked up by cassandra during boot.
For that, u need to stop the server and restart it.

For this.

go to apache-cassandra/bin : run stop-server.bat
then run cassandra.bat

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE test2.state2 (state text , "cqltypes.UnitedStatesState" text, PRIMARY KEY (state));
```